# Swipe to change page - different domain

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

I've seen a lot of posts on mobile slide buttons already, but those are always about loading divs on the same page or another page on the same domain. I'm trying to do almost the same thing but to a different domain. This is what I have

http://jsfiddle.net/yxzZf/3898/

```
$("#listitem").swiperight(function() {
    $.mobile.changePage("http://www.google.com");
});$("#listitem").swipeleft(function() {
    $.mobile.changePage("http://www.google.com");
});
```

As you can see, when you slide the button it does not load another domain, it just sits there with its "I'm trying min, I'm trying" icon and nothing else happens. I don't use jquery much at all and can't find an alternative to $.mobile.changePage that will load a different domain. 
Anyone know something that can solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`$.mobile.changePage()`](http://api.jquerymobile.com/jQuery.mobile.changePage/) when you want to load a page via Ajax.

To move to a new domain or load a page without Ajax, use `window.location.href`.

```
$("#listitem").on("swiperight", function () {
  window.location.href = "http://www.google.com";
});

$("#listitem").on("swipeleft", function () {
  window.location.href = "http://www.yahoo.com";
});
```

> **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/T67fr/)**

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
$(document).on("swipeleft","#listitem",function(){
  $.mobile.changePage("http://www.google.com");
});

$(document).on("swiperight","#listitem",function(){
  $.mobile.changePage("http://www.google.com");
});
```

Comment: That doesn't seem to work either
`<script type="text/javascript">//<![CDATA[ 
$(window).load(function(){
$(document).on("swipeleft", "#listitem", function () {
    $.mobile.changePage("http://www.google.com");
});

$(document).on("swiperight", "#listitem", function () {
    $.mobile.changePage("http://www.google.com");
});
});//]]>  

</script>`
is how I have it in the source